# A rectangle P is divided into smaller rectangles by segments parallel to its sides. We call a point a t-point if its a vertex of two small rectangles.

Tags: number-theory, rectangles, parity

A rectangle P is divided by segments parallel to its sides into smaller rectangles. We call a point a t-point if it is a vertex of exactly two such small rectangles. Prove that the number of t-points is even.

Answer (score 3):

There are 3 kinds of points: t-point ($x$ points), points of the initial rectangle P (4 points) and points which are vertex of 4 rectangles($y$ points).

Suppose there are $n$ rectangles.

We calculate the total angle of these rectangles:
$$2n\pi = 2x \frac{\pi}{2}+ 4 \frac{\pi}{2} +4y  \frac{\pi}{2} $$
Then
$$2n =x+2+2y$$
Hence, $x$ must be even number. Q.E.D

Answer (score 0):

$t $ points should live on the outer,  big rectangle. Now if such a point is one side then another one should live on the opposite side of the big regtangle.  I think this is enough.

Unless by segments you mean not parallels lines that cut the initial rectangle into 2 points then $t$ points can be also  an odd number. [image]

Is the point A,  the only t point?

Comment: Can you show an example of that last claim?

Comment: @DavidK, Not really....because as far as I see now, Iassumed wrong..

Comment: @David K, I have added some picture to clarify.

Comment: @dmtri A is not the only t-point. In fact, there are 4 t-points in the graphic.
Besides, your example seems not correct because the initital rectangle is not divided into smaller rectangles (there are other forms that are not rectangles)

Comment: @NN2, OK thanks a lot!